# How to connect list and if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I am trying to make a trivia program that asks 10 questions to the user and displays if the user's input matches with correct answers or not.

My code:

```
class Question:
    
    def __init__(self):
        global qDictionary
    
        self.qDictionary = { # My questions
        '1':
"""
    Q1. What does “www” stand for in a website browser?
    
    1) World Wide Web
    2) World Wide World
    3) Web Wide World
    4) Web World Wide
""",
# (Other questions ...)
        '10':
"""
    Q10. Who was the president of USSR when Chernobyl Power Plant exploded?
    
    1) Vladimir Lenin
    2) Vladimir Putin
    3) Mikhail Gorbachev
    4) Joseph Stalin
"""
}    
        global count, answer, userAnswer, user1score, user2score
        count = 0
        user1score = 0
        user2score = 0
        answer = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3,
                  1, 4, 1, 2, 3] # I am thinking of using dictionary here but not sure

        def result(self):
            print("User1, your score is: ", user1score)        
        
        for count in range(0, 10):
            count = count + 1
            count = str(count)
            
            self.quiz = self.qDictionary[count]
            print(self.quiz)
        
            userAnswer = int(input("Answer: "))
            
            if userAnswer == answer[userAnswer]:
                print("Correct!")
                user1score += 1
                user2score += 1
            else:
                print("Incorrect!")
            
        result(self)
        
c = Question()
```

Error:

```
    Q1. What does “www” stand for in a website browser?
    
    1) World Wide Web
    2) World Wide World
    3) Web Wide World
    4) Web World Wide

Answer: 1 # 1 is the correct answer but the program still recognizes it as an incorrect answer
Incorrect!
```

The problem is that I want to make a working list of correct answers that accepts the user's input, but every time I try to make it work, it generates an error. How should I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It technically generates no error but the result is not what I expect:     Q1. What does “www” stand for in a website browser?
    
    1) World Wide Web
    2) World Wide World
    3) Web Wide World
    4) Web World Wide

Answer: 1
Incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

In this condition check `userAnswer == answer[userAnswer]`, you are fetching the answer using an incorrect variable, you should use `count` rather than the userAnswer which is actually user's input.

`userAnswer == answer[int(count)]` to be exact.

Comment: Oh now I see. I didn't think about using ```count```. Thanks for your answer